# Связь со многими без дублирования

Tags: sql

Извиняюсь, не знаю как корректно сформулировать заголовок.

Есть таблица "Цвета":

```
ID | Name  
----------
0  | White  
1  | Black 
...
```

Есть таблица "Детали":

```
ID | Name  | ColorID
0  | Part1 | 0
1  | Part1 | 1
...
N  | PartN | 0
```

Чтобы получить все доступные цвета детали можно написать запрос вида:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.Name, t.Name FROM Parts s LEFT JOIN Colors t on s.ColorID = t.ID
```

На данный момент, если деталь существует в N цветах, то в таблице создается N записей, по одной на каждый цвет. Можно ли исключить это дублирование и привести таблицу к виду вроде:

```
ID | Name  | ColorID
0  | Part1 | 0, 1 ...
```

Но при этом как-то сохранить возможность джоинов по ИД цвета, чтобы запросом вытащить имена цветов?

Ответ: так делать нельзя!

Comment: Можно. Вам нужен group by и какая нибудь функция для сборки списка через запятую. В каждой СУБД используются свои функции. Например в MySQL это group_concat, в Oracle listagg, postgresql string_agg и т.п.

Comment: Зачем так делать? Это же нарушает нормализацию.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, вопрос грубо в том, есть ли способ и нормализацию сохранить и дублирования избежать)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, может можно поле таблицы объявить как множество и работать с ним в запросах соответствующим образом, как таблица в таблице

Comment: @goldstar_labs но зачем? Почему не хранить данные отдельными строками?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, пытаюсь избежать дублирования)

Comment: @goldstar_labs это неправильный подход. Ваша БД не станет от этого существенно меньше, но станет медленнее и менее удобна в работе.

Comment: *есть ли способ и нормализацию сохранить и дублирования избежать* Нет. Потому что Вы не понимаете, что такое "дублирование". Вы себе придумали, что если одно поле повторяется, то это дублирование - так вот, это бред. Дублирование - это когда ВСЕ поля записей содержат те же значения. Хоть одно поле различается - всё, ни разу не дубль.

Comment: Три таблицы: Цвета, Детали, Цвета деталей. Третья - многое-ко-многому с двумя полями ИД_Детали и ИД_Цвета. Сделать "дублей" ещё меньше можно только пожертвовав нормализацией. В этом случае не ясно зачем вам вообще база - храните всё в файликах на диске.

Comment: @Lexx918, херово что в 2019м поле таблицы не может быть множеством

Comment: @goldstar_labs зависит от СУБД. у вас не указано с какой вы работаете. Оракл давно умеет играть во вложенные таблицы. в мускуле тоже вроде как появились json-типы полей. а есть ещё популярный постгрис. либо можно посмотреть в сторону no-sql баз типа монги. всё в ваших руках.